# The project of Inno Setup for Windows 64-bit

Tags: installation, inno-setup, win64

I had created the project via Inno Setup for Windows 64-bit (e.g. Win 7 / 8).
After Installed I have detected that the files of the handbook can not open!
Code of my project the Inno Setup below.

How can I solve it problem? 
Where my error in it the project?

```
#define MyAppName "MyProgram"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Publish Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.mydomen.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "myprogram.exe"

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
LicenseFile=C:\Users\path_to_my_program\Win64\Debug\license-ru.txt
InfoAfterFile=C:\Users\path_to_my_program\Win64\Debug\readme-ru.txt
OutputDir=C:\Users\Documents\Inno Setup\Setups
OutputBaseFilename=myprogramsetup64
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\path_to_my_program\myprogram_Icon.ico
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "russian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "    {cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\path_to_my_program\Win64\Debug\myprogram.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\path_to_my_program\Win64\Debug\SQLite3.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\path_to_my_program\Win64\Debug\help\handbook-ru.pdf"; DestDir: "{app}\help"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\path_to_my_program\Win64\Debug\help\handbook-en.pdf"; DestDir: "{app}\help"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,   {#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

After Installed I can not to open from my program the help files - handbook-ru.pdf and handbook-en.pdf. It is problem.

I had in my program used code:

```
procedure TForm1.MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  path_to_handbook : WideString;
begin
  case language of
    $0019 : path_to_handbook := 'help\handbook-ru.pdf'; // Russian
    $0009 : path_to_handbook := 'help\handbook-en.pdf'; // English
  end;

  ShellExecuteW(Handle, nil, PWideChar(path_to_handbook), nil,  nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

In debug and runtime the help files had been to open excellent!

And still...

The program is normally installed only with the rights of the administrator.

If Installed with the administrator right then the help files not open and the my program - working well.
If Installed without the administrator right then the help files open well but the my program - working with errors.

Any ideas how to correct a code in Inno Setup.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "cannot open" is a vague description. You need to go deeper to see what's up after the installation, and post more details to this question.

Comment: The `ShellExecute` function returns value, which you should definitely check in your Delphi/FreePascal application. My guess is that it returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` because of that relative path you've used there (since you're in a different working directory). I would suggest you to always use the absolute path to the file.

Comment: I solved my problem with absolute path - ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName). Stay problem with the administrator rights. My program can be installed correctly only with the administrator rights. Where I have errors in a my code Inno Setup? Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't see any problem in your Inno Setup script. The installer has to run elevated because you're going to write to the "Program Files" folder which needs admin rights since Windows Vista, so it must be installed with admin rights. The application is then executed (I mean the execution if you check the "Run application" check box on the final page) with the original user rights (non-elevated), so it's the same as if you were executing it e.g. from start menu. So even this doesn't point to something unusual. Have you checked what returns your `ShellExecute` function call ?

Comment: Excuse me, I have been hurried, the absolute path has registered, but the problem remained! The problem with the  help files also remains, as well as a problem of installation with the administrator rights. In codes Inno Setup it can is necessary to add or variate something concerning the administrator rights? Thanks

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I thought, that you're having trouble to open the help file in your application. Your Inno Setup script looks fine. It copies the help files into the application's `Help` subdirectory. What I'm suspecting from the beginning is the application itself because of the relative path used when opening the help files.